# UI not updated when ViewModel value changed

Tags: android, android-databinding, android-livedata, android-viewmodel

I have created sample app to demo my question:

A `TextView` and a `Button`, text view visibility is bound to `viewModel.bar`

I want the button to switch the value of `viewModel.bar` when clicked and the UI to get updated as well.

However, this is not happening. The value is changed but the UI is not updated.

Layout File:

```
<layout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

    <data>
        <import type="android.view.View"/>
        <variable name="viewModel"
                  type="com.example.bindingone.MainViewModel"/>
    </data>

    <android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            tools:context=".MainActivity">

        <TextView
                android:id="@+id/text_view"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Hello World"
                android:visibility="@{viewModel.bar ? View.VISIBLE : View.GONE}"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"/>

        <Button
                android:text="Update UI"
                android:onClick="clicked"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

    </android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>

</layout>
```

`MainActivity` File:

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    private val viewModel = MainViewModel()

    private lateinit var binding: ActivityMainBinding

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

        binding = DataBindingUtil.setContentView(this, R.layout.activity_main)
        binding.viewModel = viewModel
    }

    fun clicked(v: View) {
        viewModel.bar.value = viewModel.bar.value?.not() ?: false
    }
}
```

`MainViewModel` file:

```
class MainViewModel : ViewModel() {
    var bar = MutableLiveData<Boolean>()
}
```

Comment: Make sure your view model has `@Bindable` annotation set on property getters and it notifies the view in the setter like `BR.notifyPropertyChanged(BR.prop)`

Comment: @VahidAmiri "@Bindable" is needed when using base observable. he is using LiveData which doesn't need annotation.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

After creating binding, add this line `binding.setLifecycleOwner(this)`.

```
/**
 * Sets the {@link LifecycleOwner} that should be used for observing changes of
 * LiveData in this binding. If a {@link LiveData} is in one of the binding expressions
 * and no LifecycleOwner is set, the LiveData will not be observed and updates to it
 * will not be propagated to the UI.
 *
 * @param lifecycleOwner The LifecycleOwner that should be used for observing changes of
 *                       LiveData in this binding.
 */
@MainThread
public void setLifecycleOwner(@Nullable LifecycleOwner lifecycleOwner)
```

Comment: why is this needed?? @Dewey

Comment: @Anmol Databinding needs a hook between it and ViewModel so it can know when data is changed and it should be updated. This method is the hook.

Comment: It is a world wonder that even when a `viewmodel` object has been assigned to the `binding` object, an explicit `setLifecycleOwner()` call still needs to be made before the expected/intended result happens.